# How can I use Zend Libraries inside symfony 2.0

Tags: zend-framework, symfony

What is the best way to access Zend Autoloader inside my Symfony bundle so that I can use Zend Libraries ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Zend components or any other 3rd party libraries inside a Symfony2 project is really easy.

1.) Download Zend and extract it into the "vendor" folder.

2.) Register Zend by adding the following into the $loader->registerPrefixes params

```
    'Zend_'  => __DIR__.'/../vendor/Zend/library',
```

Please keep in mind to add the right path here...

3.) You are good to go and can now use Zend's classes inside your Symyfony2 project.